# Formatting exported excel file in laravel

Tags: excel, laravel, formatting, export

I use the maatwebsite/excel package to produce excel files from database tables. The export is successful, but I need some help with formatting it.

In fact I want the excel to have bigger font size for headings, highlighted headings and borders.

So far I have succeeded only in creating bigger size header fonts using setSize() as you can see in my code excerpt.

My exports file (\laravel\app\Exports\MembersExport.php) is the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Member;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings; 
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;

class MembersExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize, WithEvents
{

    public function collection()
    {
        return Member::all();
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return 
        [
            'head1',
            'head2',
            'head3',
            'head4',
            'head5',
        'head6',
        'head7',
        ];
    }

     public function registerEvents(): array
        {
        return [
            AfterSheet::class    => function(AfterSheet $event) 
            {

                       $cellRange = 'A1:G1'; // All headers
                       $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cellRange)->getFont()->setName('Calibri');
               $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cellRange)->getFont()->setSize(14);


            },
              ];
       }   
}
```

I want to integrate something like the following to the code above. Could you help me please?

```
$styleArray = [
    'borders' => [
        'outline' => [
            'borderStyle' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THICK,
            'color' => ['argb' => 'FFFF0000'],
        ],
    ],
];

$worksheet->getStyle('A1:G1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there.

```
// null if cell range not found
$cellsToChange = $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cellRange);

if ($cellsToChange) {
    $cellToChange->applyFromArray($styleArray);
}
```

Should do the trick.